# jquery Активировать cehckbox по нажатию на radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, почему у меня не получается активировать checkbox при условии что радио для активирован

То есть по нажатию на radio, должно быть нажато и checkbox

```js
$('input#option1').on('change', function() {
    $('.wpcf7-checkbox#option1 span input[type="checkbox"]').val( $(this).val() );
});

$("input#option1").on('change', function() {
    $('.wpcf7-checkbox#option1 span input[type="checkbox"]').val(['1']);
});

$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', function(){
    $('.wpcf7-checkbox#option1 span input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="option1">

<span class="wpcf7-checkbox" id="option1">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может кому-то, когда-то и понадобится:

```js
$('input#option1').on('change', function() {
    $('#option1 input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="option1">

<span class="wpcf7-checkbox" id="option1">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Id должны быть уникальными для элементов